# Query no working after upgrading Yii2 version

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm migrating a Yii2 app from Yii 2.0.6 to Yii 2.0.37

There is this SQL query used to initialize an SqlDataProvider:

```
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM new_form nf JOIN company_quote_log cql ON nf.log_id = cql.log_id JOIN company_quote_status_log cqsl ON cql.id = cqsl.company_quote_log_id WHERE cqsl.status_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) GROUP BY cql.log_id',
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'form_id' => SORT_DESC
        ], 
        'attributes' => ['crdate', 'form_id']
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 5550,
    ]
]);
```

The 3 tables have an `id` column.

In the old version, it executes perfect. In the new version it throws:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'
```

It seems is required to rename columns to make Yii accepts this query.

MySql server is the same version in both environments.

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *`, besides that is **bad** programming, as you can see you have 2 id files after joining

Comment: Not 2, there are 3 columns named `id`. But the new_form table have A LOT of columns, more than 100 (not my design). Is there a workaround, or the columns have to be listed explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by explicitly naming JUST the columns that are **really required** for the context, the ones used in the `GridView`.

This is bad code in general. `SELECT table.* ...` is bad practice as [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk) mentions in a comment.